# How to count cumulative number of implied groupings in a single column of a dataframe in base R or dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

Suppose we start with this data frame `myDF` generated by the code immediately beneath:

```
> myDF
  index
1     2
2     2
3     4
4     4
5     6
6     6
7     6
```

Generating code: `myDF <- data.frame(index = c(2,2,4,4,6,6,6))`

I'd like to add a column `cumGrp` to data frame `myDF` that provides a cumulative count of implicitly grouped elements, as illustrated below. Any suggestions of simple concise base R or dplyr code to do this?

```
> myDF
  index cumGrp   cumGrp explained
1     2      1   1st grouping of same index numbers (2) adjacent to each other
2     2      1   Same as above
3     4      2   2nd grouping of same index numbers (4) adjacent to each other
4     4      2   Same as above
5     6      3   3rd grouping of same index numbers (6) adjacent to each other
6     6      3   Same as above
7     6      3   Same as above
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many possible ways:

**`dplyr::cur_group_id`**

```r
library(dplyr)
myDF %>% 
  group_by(index) %>% 
  mutate(cumGrp = cur_group_id())
```

**`cumsum`**

```r
library(dplyr)
myDF %>% 
  mutate(cumGrp = cumsum(index != lag(index, default = 0)))
```

**`as.numeric` + `factor`**

```r
myDF |>
  transform(cumGrp = as.numeric(factor(index)))
```

**`data.table::.GRP`**

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(myDF)[, num := .GRP, by = index]
```

**`match`**

```r
myDF |>
  transform(cumGrp = match(index, unique(index)))
```

**`collapse::group`**

```r
library(collapse)
myDF |>
  settransform(cumGrp = group(index))
```